# Bound for a integral

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two bounded nonnegative functions, does it hold that if $g(x)\leq L$ then $$\int_0^T f(x)g(x)dx\leq L \int_0^T f(x)dx$$

I think the answer is yes as it follows from monotonicity property of Lebesgue integral and $f(x)g(x)\leq f(x)L$. Since $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are bounded, the inequality above indeed make sense. Is it right?

Comment: Yes. This is still true if f is just integrable. Nonnegativity is superfluous as well if you assume g is bounded.

Comment: @JamesYang Is it not neccesary to assume that $g$ is also integrable? In other case $fg$ could not be integrable.

Comment: @JamesYang Are you sure that nonnegativity is superfluous? As I cannot have $f(x)g(x) \leq f(x)L$ almost everywhere if $f(x)$ is negative for some point.

Comment: @mfl $g$ is bounded and thus integrable.

Comment: @JamesYang A bounded function is Lebesgue integrable if measurable. This is not assumed in the OP question.

Comment: @quallenjäger sorry I meant it's superfluous for g if g is bounded, not for both f and g.

Comment: @mfl I think it's clear everything is measurable as OP used monotonocity of integrals. But yes technically you are right.

Comment: @mfl I dropped this assumption as I think it doesn't play a role in the proof. The entire question would not make sense without assumption on measurability.

Comment: So, as @JamesYang said in his first comment, you are right if you assume $f,g$ Lebesgue integrable and $0\le g \le L.$